# How could I passing lat/long from google map to winform application?

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, google-maps-api-3

currently I have design a winform based application, using webbrowser control to load google map, I idea is once use drag the marker to new position, then it should return a new lat/lon to winform.however, now I am user webbroser1.Documenttext to load the web page,and it considered the whole page as string, 
therefore, how could get the variable from javascript to C#?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not know C#, but I'm Delphi programmer and I do this. I'll explain how I do it and you implement this in C# ;-)

I have a HTML page that I load into the WebBrowser. This HTML contain some functions JS and a HTML form with fields hidden. I use the JS to communicate Delphi and Map. For example, I have a JS function to generate map, another to generate markers,... Also programmed events of map or markers or others maps objects. This events, when they are triggered, fill the HTML form. From delphi, I have a Timer that ever 200 miliseconds check the HTML form and get the new information.

I hope it helps you

Regards
cadetill